# how to copy the value from one date box to next box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how to copy the value from one date box to next box

```
<?php  $dat=date("Y-m-d");?>
<td><input type="date"  value=<?php echo $dat;?> name="from" onchange=fun1();/></td>

 <td class=to>To:<input type="date" value= name="to"></td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Like below:

```
$('input[name=to]').val($('input[name=from]').val());
```

Or if you want to copy the value form `from` to `to` when `from` changed:

```
$('input[name=from]').change(function() {
    $('input[name=to]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: shall i do it in javascript

Comment: Something I'm trying to get out of the habit of doing is unnecessary jQuery wrapping - use `this.value` instead ;)

Comment: thanks i got it $('input[name=to]').val($('input[name=from]').val());
Or if you want to copy the value form from to to when from changed:

$('input[name=from]').change(function() {
    $('input[name=to]').val($(this).val());
});